# Div not scrollable even after adding overflow css

Tags: html, css

This is my class :

```
.ticker-container {
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 40%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

The idea is that the "div" container should be scrollable.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwDZ5.png)

But for some reasons while it sets the maximum size of the div itself, it's not making it scrollable.

The html looks like this:

```
<div class="row ticker-container">
        <div class="col s6" id="ticker_container">
        </div>
        <div class="col s6" id="candidates">
        </div>
    </div>
```

And I'm appending content to the `ticker_container`. I've tried adding the class to the inside div containers but it still didn't make the div containers scrollable. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the site in production: https://smag.2501.io/

EDIT: To observe the behavior, try an input like "TESTER" in the second input field and press enter

EDIT:

```
.snowcontainer {
    background-image: radial-gradient(50% 176%, black 80%, black 100%);
    min-height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;

    &__content {
        position: relative;
        align-self: center;
        padding: 3rem 0;
    }
}

.snow {
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100vh;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.snow .svg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#snow-top-layer {
    will-change: transform;
    transform: translateY(-768px);
    animation: fall 22.5s infinite linear;
}

#snow-bottom-layer {
    will-change: transform;
    transform: translateY(-768px);
    animation: fall 45s infinite linear;
}
```

The issue was my snow containers, it was blocking the content. Added a `z-index` and it fixed the issue

Comment: to scroll what? there is no content inside

Comment: Ah, to observe the behavior, you need to add some data, try with "TESTER" in the second input field.

Comment: better add all the code here and be very clear ... no one will go to your webiste, test it, debug and get back to answer ... and if we do so you will correct the issue on the site and the question will become irrelevant since no one will see the issue again in the future

Comment: Thanks @temaniafif I'll edit my question to contain the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your div.content position: relative; and some z-index. The div.snow is covering the element.

Comment: That was the issue! Thank you, the snow flakes was blocking it

Answer (score 0):

Unit percent always relates to the size of a parent element.

It happens that if no parent has explicitly defined a height, percents height can not be determined.

Wrap `.ticker-container` into `.wrapper` and specify an explicit height (e.g. `px`, `vh`, `rem`, `em`).

Since value of `max-height` overwrites value of `height` it does not make sense to use for both percent. May use `px` for `max-height` or skip `height`.

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 90vh;
}

.ticker-container {
  max-height: 50%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <hr>
  <ul class="ticker-container">
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In, sed. Blanditiis architecto voluptates amet, rem temporibus vero quasi ex? Qui illum laudantium molestias unde doloremque quae libero. Autem, culpa voluptatibus!</li>
    <li>Atque voluptatum cumque quisquam maiores sunt provident incidunt explicabo? Sunt sequi asperiores delectus suscipit reprehenderit laboriosam nihil ad odit deleniti itaque saepe fugiat consequuntur quas exercitationem, maiores accusamus quod quis?</li>
    <li>Officiis nihil consequuntur amet vitae minima esse quaerat fuga, similique explicabo, aut quam cupiditate, eum nobis ratione aliquid maiores deleniti. Excepturi impedit provident similique atque cum est voluptatum eveniet ipsam!</li>
    <li>Voluptatibus quo est necessitatibus cum harum ratione pariatur rem fugit, dolore, amet deleniti magni maxime autem nam. Enim numquam perferendis at sint odio. Nemo vel quidem, odio aliquid optio velit?</li>
    <li>Quisquam velit non, ea exercitationem totam laborum. Nam, cum iure commodi adipisci distinctio voluptatum eius quos quas dolorum voluptas sit necessitatibus magnam quibusdam? Animi tempore rem minus nihil rerum nobis.</li>
    <li>Tempore et sint facilis eius itaque incidunt iusto soluta eos nobis ad est error minima fugiat, ea voluptatem mollitia suscipit maiores eveniet sunt natus officiis magnam dolore! Perspiciatis, officia culpa!</li>
    <li>At voluptas reiciendis possimus aut, cum explicabo corporis et incidunt sint. Quisquam ducimus magni id blanditiis sunt suscipit laborum nam reprehenderit, voluptate praesentium fugit quis repudiandae alias beatae dolorem! Vero.</li>
    <li>Nostrum ratione sit quas. Quibusdam eos sunt suscipit perferendis, in ad accusantium quam harum, quis natus placeat fugit, aspernatur eligendi sit vel. Libero ratione neque eligendi rem excepturi provident voluptatibus.</li>
    <li>Quisquam aspernatur minima atque nobis. Sint possimus laudantium, accusantium explicabo id repellendus saepe debitis sunt eos fugit tenetur, illum facere ratione, voluptas assumenda architecto quas aperiam ab enim tempore quod?</li>
    <li>Corporis illo illum sequi fugit exercitationem neque nulla sunt magnam nobis alias nihil delectus porro et itaque, iure maiores vel quia deserunt? Minima quia repudiandae libero officiis ipsum, pariatur doloremque.</li>
    <li>Quis aut, illum laboriosam, nemo asperiores temporibus facilis, quas magnam rerum dignissimos quidem excepturi quam. Earum reiciendis voluptate laboriosam animi. Nam qui, quaerat error minima consequatur reprehenderit quasi voluptatum quidem.</li>
    <li>Magnam debitis quisquam labore, tempora sapiente soluta mollitia quas, ex animi iste dicta, dolorum rem consequuntur fugit quidem dolores a laborum nemo qui autem molestiae quod vero aliquam! Dicta, quo.</li>
    <li>Eligendi iusto accusamus voluptatem aliquid, dolor quisquam perspiciatis pariatur cupiditate optio est, itaque rem soluta facere commodi nam beatae nemo necessitatibus debitis. Nisi, tenetur? Ipsa labore laboriosam harum nulla repellat.</li>
    <li>Quidem quos quod blanditiis accusantium tenetur perspiciatis qui dolorum perferendis, cumque, similique omnis enim hic praesentium doloribus dolorem. Sit saepe atque optio voluptatibus perspiciatis amet ad neque facilis dolorem unde.</li>
    <li>Quia, veniam quidem iusto adipisci voluptates magni at architecto tenetur numquam fugiat molestiae beatae inventore praesentium, recusandae impedit aliquid laudantium nihil libero pariatur totam sequi provident omnis soluta. Quam, labore!</li>
    <li>Molestiae perferendis nulla doloremque corporis, pariatur ipsum, tempore assumenda quo odio doloribus magni mollitia eaque magnam consequuntur possimus totam facere. Nemo libero soluta, dolores ex maiores quia delectus dignissimos labore.</li>
    <li>Officiis quam, perferendis aut minima eaque provident modi accusamus repudiandae officia quae. Necessitatibus deleniti laudantium porro quam nesciunt et aut id illo ea inventore, ullam consequatur officia eum voluptatibus corrupti.</li>
    <li>Accusantium magni itaque libero repudiandae, veniam odit iste. Laboriosam consectetur eius minima numquam suscipit iusto odit. Vel, dolorem earum, aut soluta ullam accusantium magnam, eos voluptates dignissimos aperiam ipsam error.</li>
    <li>Facilis asperiores dignissimos, repellat nisi molestias velit perspiciatis nihil consequuntur consectetur necessitatibus odit ex corporis laborum iste quae quas, saepe in debitis doloribus ad magni maiores porro temporibus. Ratione, hic?</li>
    <li>Veniam sunt iure repellendus fugit minima quas culpa esse natus temporibus rem nisi quaerat iste modi similique quis a vero odit eos dignissimos adipisci quos, in blanditiis. Architecto, soluta aperiam.</li>
  </ul>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: My issue appeared to be SVG drawing on top of the div container.